# Not able to override a script method using metaClass

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I am trying to override a method defined in a Groovy custom `Script` class by redefining the method via the object's `metaClass`, however the change is completely ignored and the original method gets called as is. I tried the same on a regular class and it worked as expected, so I am wondering what is different in case of a custom `Script`. Here is a snippet that I saved as `/tmp/t.groovy:

```
class Worker {
    def init() {
        throw new Exception('I always fail')
    }

    void start() {
        init()
        println('I never get to work')
    }
}

def worker = new Worker()
worker.metaClass.init = { println("dummy init") }
worker.start()

def shell = new GroovyShell()
def script = shell.parse('@groovy.transform.BaseScript TestScript _')
script.metaClass.init = { println("dummy init") }
script.start()
```

Where the class `TestScript` has to be defined in its own file for `GroovyShell` to find it, so `/tmp/TestScript.groovy` has the class:

```
abstract class TestScript extends Script {
    def init() {
        throw new Exception('I always fail')
    }

    void start() {
        init()
        println('I never get to work')
    }
}
```

Here is the output when I ran using Groovy 2.4.14 on Mac OS:

```
$ groovy /tmp/t.groovy
dummy init
I never get to work
Caught: java.lang.Exception: I always fail
java.lang.Exception: I always fail
    at TestScript.init(TestScript.groovy:3)
    at TestScript.start(TestScript.groovy:7)
    at TestScript$start.call(Unknown Source)
    at t.run(t.groovy:19)
```

You can see that the change done to `worker.metaClass` was effective, but the same done to the `script.metaClass` was ignored. I tried tracing the calls first on the working scenario, using something like this:

```
def worker = new Worker()
def m = new DelegatingMetaClass(worker.metaClass) {
        Object invokeMethod(Object object, String methodName, Object[] args) {
            println("invokeMethod ${methodName}(${args})")
            return super.invokeMethod(object, methodName, args)
        }

    }
m.initialize()
worker.metaClass = m
worker.start()
```

The output looks like this:

```
invokeMethod start([])
invokeMethod init([])
Caught: java.lang.Exception: I always fail
java.lang.Exception: I always fail
    ...
```

You can see that both `start` and `init` get logged. When I tried the same on the script object:

```
def shell = new GroovyShell()
def script = shell.parse('@groovy.transform.BaseScript TestScript _')
def m = new DelegatingMetaClass(script.metaClass) {
        Object invokeMethod(Object object, String methodName, Object[] args) {
            println("invokeMethod ${methodName}(${args})")
            return super.invokeMethod(object, methodName, args)
        }

    }
m.initialize()
script.metaClass = m
script.start()
```

The output looks like:

```
invokeMethod start([])
Caught: java.lang.Exception: I always fail
java.lang.Exception: I always fail
    ...
```

You can see that the call to `init` never gets delegated to `invokeMethod`. What am I missing here?

Comment: it definitely does not work. but why do you need script parsing? why not just a class parsing?

Comment: I am testing Jenkins pipeline var files that get loaded as Script files. Any idea why scripts could be defying the normal Groovy metaprogramming model as documented here: https://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html ?

Comment: Have you tried this library for testing Jenkins pipeline - https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit ?

Comment: Yes, I already do, but sadly vars tested using this approach (perhaps a JaCoCo issue) do not generate any coverage data, so I have been trying an alternative approach of moving the code from the var file into a custom script that extends `CpsScript` and declare it as the `BaseScript` in the var file. This has worked well so far except for a few oddities.

Comment: @haridsv, actually if you do `def script = new TestScript()` then everything works fine. so, by loading TestScript as a class solves the problem. issue appears only by using `@groovy.transform.BaseScript`

Comment: @daggett Yes, I could create a concrete test class for this purpose, though creating the object directly instead of going through `PipelineTestHelper.loadScript()` would probably mean more manual work of wiring some things together. I will try this a shot, thank you.

Comment: @daggett I am able to create inline concrete test classes (only need to define a blank run method) and be able to use them by setting the `binding` to the one given by JenkinsPipelineUnit. Looking at the implementation of `PipelineTestHelper.loadScript()`, I can see that this bypasses some interceptions, but I don't seem to be missing them in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Implementing `GroovyInterceptable` makes the script methods overridable via the metaclass.

I started looking for clues by comparing the normalized stacktraces leading up to the `Worker.init` and `TestScript.init` by adding `def t = new Throwable(); t.fillInStackTrace(); t.printStackTrace()` to both the methods. The part that looks significantly different are the stack leading from `start()` to `init()` as seen below:

```
For Worker class:

    at Worker.init(t.groovy:3)
    at Worker$init$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:161)
    at Worker.start(t.groovy:8)
    at Worker$start.call(Unknown Source)

For TestScript class:

    at TestScript.init(TestScript.groovy:3)
    at TestScript.start(TestScript.groovy:8)
    at TestScript$start.call(Unknown Source)
```

You can see that the call to `init` from `start` went through the groovy code in `Worker`, where as it went directly in `TestScript`.

Then I noticed that [`Script`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.15/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html) extends [`GroovyObjectSupport`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.15/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyObjectSupport.html) which is meant to be a base class for Java classes to extend when their objects should appear as Groovy objects. When I searched for `GroovyObjectSupport` under the [metaprogramming documentation](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html#_groovyobject_interface), I came across the fact that `invokeMethod` only works in conjunction with the marker interface [`GroovyInterceptable`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.15/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyInterceptable.html) and that it is lacking in the class inheritance chain of the `Script` class. Once I made `TestScript` implement `GroovyInterceptable`, the override worked as expected.

I still have to check if adding this interface will make Jenkins pipeline CPS scoff at me.

Comment: There is still a puzzle here that I can't understand. I noticed that a simple Java class with no special Groovy decorators can be modified in Groovy without any additional work. The pure Java classes come with an associated metaclass and I am able to add methods and override existing ones, just like for a pure Groovy class. I don't know why a Script class is different and needing `GroovyInterceptable` and more importantly, what the advantage of explicitly implementing `GroovyObject` is if Groovy gives everything to Java classes even when not implementing this interface.

Comment: While implementing `GroovyInterceptable` solved the issue in the standalone usecase, I couldn't get it to work in a Spock test that uses JenkinsPipelineUnit framework. For some reason, all invocations on the object end up getting delegated to something that just ignores them. What I finally ended up doing was to instantiate the object directly instead of going through `GroovyShell` (see the comment from @daggett and my responses).